# create 3D surface (CGAL::make_surface_mesh) by set(10 million ) of points 3D

Tags: c++, cgal, surface

I have 10 million points as input data and I want to create 3D surface(3D-Delaunay triangulation) by them.
I understand that I should use CGAL library.
In example [here](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Surface_mesher/Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example.html) as input data is sphere and it is defined by formula.

I want to create surface by points, not by formula.
Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The link you give cannot take points as input.  Please have a look at several algorithms for [surface reconstruction](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PartReconstruction) for point sets.

Comment: tell me please, if I execute this [code](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Scale_space_reconstruction_3/Scale_space_reconstruction_3_2scale_space_8cpp-example.html), will there be a closure of the surface? I want to get a surface of triangles for further ray tracing.